# Symfony dynamic form fields in event subscriber

Tags: symfony

Following the example as documented in the following http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

This adds the fields in the event subscriber first, then adds the fields that have been added in the form type.

Does anybody know how to change the ordering around so that the form type fields appear first in the form view, then the fields added in the event subscriber appear after?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by moving form building ($builder->add(...)) from MyFormType::buildForm() to  listener leaving there only $builder->addEventSubscriber(...) statement.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different manner to order your fields,

- When building your form, you've to add fields according to the order
  you went to display them, it allows you to get the right behavior
  using `form_widget(form)`.
- [Customize your form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). You can then put every part of
  your form in the right position so that it looks the way you want.

Comment: fields are added exactly as i want to display them however when i register the event subscriber after adding two fields to the form, then fields registered in the event subscriber appear before the ones already added in the form type

Comment: Why don't you just order your field in your template?

Comment: well i've developed a form theme and ordering in the template would mean i'd have to duplicate quite a bit of that code which i dont really want to do, seems a hack. All i wanted to do was just add the form fields in the subscriber after the form type fields, i thought this would be fairly easy...